# py2exe not compiling VideoCapture correctly

Tags: python, pygame, py2exe

I have created a program that takes pictures with your webcam.

I used Pygame and VideoCapture. It all works fine as `.pyw` file, but after it is compiled with py2exe it is just doesn't work.

From my research, the error is coming from trying to compile the VideoCapture module.
PLEEASSEE HELP ME!!!
(The Same error occurs for Pyinstaller)

Comment: Any luck with this? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

have you tried compiling with cx_freeze?

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys i finally can make an executable file with cx_freeze which that can work with camera and the solution is you should to copy vidcapture.pyd into your file that have your program

[this image is my file which have vidcapture.pyd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njur0.png)